# Can't get PDO to return any result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why can't I get this code to work?

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydB", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Sensor");

$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
 foreach ($data as $row) {
   echo $row['SensorID'];
}
```

`fetchAll()` only returns an empty array.

mydB is an arbitrary database.
The query works perfectly from the MySQL console.

Comment: See if there is some error `$conn->errorInfo()`

Comment: Hmmmm, you do not have any real error checking at all.

Comment: What this query produce against database via phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is correct. `print_r($conn->errorInfo());` should show you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work: "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydB"

Try: "mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=mydB"

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, today it worked. I sat with the code late night(Europe time) yesterday and must have missed something.